# Filter Stored Procedure Result (Informix)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I have a Informix database. This database contain a stored procedure with name of 'sp_agent_details' that get two DateTime Parameter. This stored procedure results about 27 columns and I want only few columns of it for reporting. I try this syntax:

```
select AGENT_NAME, AGENT_LOGIN_ID from 
       TABLE(sp_agent_detail('2014-02-04 04:00:00', '2014-02-04 23:00:00'))
```

This Result such Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal SQL statement in SPL routine.
```

Next I try this syntax:

```
select AGENT_NAME, AGENT_LOGIN_ID from 
       TABLE(MULTISET{sp_agent_call_summary 
    ('2014-02-04 04:00:00', '2014-02-04 23:00:00')})
```

Result:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Function (informix.sp_agent_call_summary) 
returns too many values.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to map your result columns of the SP to columnames (in the order they are returned by the procedure ! ).

So your statement will become:

```
select AGENT_NAME, AGENT_LOGIN_ID from 
   TABLE(sp_agent_detail('2014-02-04 04:00:00', '2014-02-04 23:00:00'))(AGENT_NAME, AGENT_LOGIN_ID, other columns that are returned by your SP)
```

Comment: I used your statement but It's Result is Error like this:
java.sql.SQLException: A syntax error has occurred.

:(

Comment: Also I removed the "," after TABLE statement and then enter statement but I received this error message again: "java.sql.SQLException: Illegal SQL statement in SPL routine."

Comment: I edited my first answer, their was a small error, removed a ','.

Comment: @HojjatJashnniloofar , the copilot answer is corret. Since you duplicate the answer at dba.stackexchange [I answer there with code example...](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60498/16135)

Comment: @Copilot: Your Answer is correct but this statement could not solve my problem. I use this statement and I also received an error. `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal SQL statement in SPL routine.`

Comment: Then maybe it's some driver error as he doesn't really recognizes the sql statement.